# In Keras what is the difference between Conv2DTranspose and Conv2D

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, deconvolution

I'm currently building a GAN with Tensorflow 2 and Keras and noticed a lot of the existing Neural Networks for the generator and discriminator use Conv2D and Conv2DTranspose in Keras.

I'm struggling to find something that functionally explains the difference between the two. Can anyone explain what these two different options for making a NN in Keras mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Conv2D` applies **Convolutional** operation on the input. On the contrary, `Conv2DTranspose` applies a **Deconvolutional** operation on the input.

- `Conv2D` is mainly used when you want to **detect features**, e.g., in the **encoder part** of an autoencoder model, and it may **shrink** your input shape.
- Conversely, `Conv2DTranspose` is used for **creating features**, for example, in the **decoder part** of an autoencoder model for constructing an image. As you can see in the code below, it makes the input shape **larger**.

```py
x = tf.random.uniform((1,3,3,1))
conv2d = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,2)(x)
print(conv2d.shape)
# (1, 2, 2, 1)
conv2dTranspose = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1,2)(x)
print(conv2dTranspose.shape)
# (1, 4, 4, 1)
```

To sum up:

- `Conv2D`:

  - May shrink your input
  - For detecting features
- `Conv2DTranspose`:

  - Enlarges your input
  - For constructing features

[image]

And if you want to know how `Conv2DTranspose` enlarges input, here you go:
[image]

For example:

```py
kernel = tf.constant_initializer(1.)
x = tf.ones((1,3,3,1))
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,2, kernel_initializer=kernel)
y = tf.ones((1,2,2,1))
de_conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1,2, kernel_initializer=kernel)

conv_output = conv(x)
print("Convolution\n---------")
print("input  shape:",x.shape)
print("output shape:",conv_output.shape)
print("input  tensor:",np.squeeze(x.numpy()).tolist())
print("output tensor:",np.around(np.squeeze(conv_output.numpy())).tolist())
'''
Convolution
---------
input  shape: (1, 3, 3, 1)
output shape: (1, 2, 2, 1)
input  tensor: [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]
output tensor: [[4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0]]
'''
de_conv_output = de_conv(y)
print("De-Convolution\n------------")
print("input  shape:",y.shape)
print("output shape:",de_conv_output.shape)
print("input  tensor:",np.squeeze(y.numpy()).tolist())
print("output tensor:",np.around(np.squeeze(de_conv_output.numpy())).tolist())
'''
De-Convolution
------------
input  shape: (1, 2, 2, 1)
output shape: (1, 3, 3, 1)
input  tensor: [[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
output tensor: [[1.0, 2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 4.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
'''
```

Comment: It's common to see code with several conv2D layers followed by several conv2DTranspose layers. The latter are supposed to revert the effect of the former. Then why do we use them if we are just getting back the original input?

Comment: @skan Hi. Thanks for your question. There can be many applications of such architecture. For example an encoder-decoder or segmentation in a U-Net-like architecture.